# Layout file loading on first view but not loading on second view with same reference path

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I have layout that is loading on one view but is not loading on another view, even though the reference paths are the same.

[image]

The app currently has a dashboard and categories page (views) which load the layout as intended. But upon clicking on the "Add Category" button (Category/Create view) the layout is not loading at all.

My category list reference to the layout
[image]

My create category reference to the layout
[image]

My Add Category button that links the Create View
[image]

So as it stands, the Admin/Index and Category/Index links on the side menu load the layout fine, but once I click "Add Category" (Category/Create) within the category view layout is lost.
[image]

**I cannot figure out what is breaking/causing this!**

This is the current state of the Category/Create view that is not able to load the layout
[image]

Comment: I don't find any any error in the code you provided, When you load Create page directly, It will also render without layout? It so strange, Maybe you can provide your project, I can test it in my environment.